# Introducing Philosophy.SE University Ambassadors Program: calling students and teachers

Tags: discussion

StackExchange is looking for students and teachers who might be interested in helping us kick off/formalize a university pizza ambassador-type program. Philosophy.StackExchange would like to sponsor university students (college or graduate) and faculty members who are excited about Philosophy, Stack Exchange and free food. Contact Seth Rogers (email Seth at stackexchange or drop a note in chat) for more details about the program and to get involved.

Students at all levels learn from these type of gatherings; interesting questions help Philosophy as a discipline and Stack Exchange as a growing resource.

Comment: You may wish to provide more details about how to contact you, for those that may be interested -- should those members who think their department might be persuaded to support the program just leave a note here?

Comment: @JosephWeissman The best way to contact me directly is email. Dropping a note in here or chat works fine too. If members think their departments are open to something different but along the same lines, contact me to discuss alternate programs.