# Introducing the Stack Exchange Research Support and Fellowship Program

Tags: discussion

The mission of Stack Exchange is to make the internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions. The Stack Exchange Fellowship Program aims to support students conducting research in subjects related to our academic Q&A sites in order to (a) increase the quality of information in a particular subject and (b) facilitate the exchange of information between experts in the field. Individual awards range from 250 to 1000 dollars (USD).

Applicants should be advanced undergraduates, graduate students or professionals pursuing research related to one of the following Stack Exchange sites:

- Philosophy
- [English](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/introducing-the-stack-exchange-research-support-and-fellowship-program)
- [Linguistics](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202/introducing-the-stack-exchange-research-support-and-fellowship-program)
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/942/introducing-stack-exchange-research-support-and-fellowship-program)
- [Theoretical Physics](http://meta.theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/questions/170/introducing-the-stack-exchange-research-support-and-fellowship-program)
- [Statistics](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/988/introducing-stack-exchange-research-support-and-fellowship-program)
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/introducing-stack-exchange-research-support-and-fellowship-program)

Applications are being accepted on a rolling basis until December 31st. For more details and to apply, check out the [application](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37818223/SE%20Fellowship%20Application.docx)!

We are also seeking volunteers from the community to help review applications. Volunteers should have some level of expertise in the subject area (professors and those who have or are pursuing advanced degrees are ideal candidates). Following the first wave of submissions, those selected to be Stack Exchange Fellows will be asked to review 3 to 4 new applications. To facilitate the review process, reviewers will rate applications on several scales instead of making judgments on funding. You can find the [Reviewer Form here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37818223/Reviewer%20Sheet.docx).

Reviewers and successful candidates are encouraged to customize the "about me" section of the user profile by including information on:

- Area of expertise and current occupation
- Key academic goals/milestones
- Role in the Fellowship program (applicant, reviewer, fellow, both)
- SE grant project, if applicable

If you have any questions regarding the Fellowship Program, or would like more information about applying or becoming a reviewer, please email academics@stackexchange.com.

Comment: No Math, hmm? That's too bad - being included in the research-off but not being included in the research.